# Can't find where an object method is defined (Askbot / Django)

Tags: python, django, askbot

I'm trying to figure out how Askbot Django-based forum works like and I came across a mystery that I can't seem to solve (newbie):

in this file:

https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel/blob/master/askbot/views/writers.py

there's this code:

```
            question = user.post_question(
                title=title,
                body_text=text,
                tags=tagnames,
                wiki=wiki,
                is_anonymous=ask_anonymously,
                is_private=post_privately,
                timestamp=timestamp,
                group_id=group_id,
                language=language)
```

The thing is, tracking down 'user' object I guess it is a 'User' object type [added](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/) by 'Authentication Middleware' to the 'HttpRequest' object as an attribute.

My question is: where in the whole Django / Askbot code is 'post_question()' defined as a 'User' object method??

I have searched across Django and Askbot documentation and code, and I give up!

Many thanks,

for more information: [Askbot](https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel) in Github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Askbot is adding the method to the `User` class. [Here's the line that does it](https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel/blob/6c9884114c59559874ccbabe4f125392c25117ae/askbot/models/__init__.py#L2873). And [here's the definition of the method](https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel/blob/6c9884114c59559874ccbabe4f125392c25117ae/askbot/models/__init__.py#L1592).